# Is it possible to change countif to an array google sheets

Tags: arrays, google-sheets

Below are two formulas that I use to determine if courses selected are full or if there is a vacancy.  I am wondering if it is possible to change these formulas to an array or if there is a workaround that would accomplish the same result.

```
=if(COUNTIF(G$2:G2,G2)<=(VLOOKUP(G2,$AC$2:$AD$50,2,0)),G2,"Full")

=if(W2="Full",if(COUNTIF({R$2:R;S$2:S;T$2:T;U$2:U;V$2:V;W$2:W},M2)
```

Edit: link to demo sheet  https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1nPhrEKhKwuq3YSghgJ4LFoHZqOzo67_b1qohh1NABJo/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Can you create a test sheet we can use? My suggestion is to use a mmult formula, but it is hard to explain without having some data to play around with.

Comment: I have included a demo sheet.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I duplicated the sheet and entered in R2

```
=Arrayformula(IF(LEN(G2:G), if(COUNTIF(G$2:G,G2:G)<=(VLOOKUP(G2:G,$AC$2:$AD$50,2,0)),G2:G,"Full"),))
```

and in S2

```
=ArrayFormula(if(len(R2:R), if(R2:R="Full",if(COUNTIF(R$2:R,H2:H)<VLOOKUP(H2:H,$AC$2:$AD$50,2,0),H2:H,"Full"),),))
```

See if that works for you?

Comment: That does show choices but it returns values that shouldn't be an option since the class is "full".  I will look at what you have provided and see if I can modify it to match what i am looking for.  Thank you!